# Trigger Gitlab Pipeline when artifact is uploaded in Jfrog

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, gitlab-ci, devops

Gitlab CI pipeline push bundled source code as artifact on jfrog as a zip file and then I need some help to trigger CD pipeline once artifact is uploaded to Jfrog.

I have tried trigger option available in Gitlab but it does not trigger pipeline when an event like uploading artifact on jfrog occurs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by triggering a webhook from JFrog - docs [here](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-platform-administration-documentation/webhooks) as soon as your artifact is uploaded. The webhook should point to GitLab to trigger a new pipeline.

From GitLab this is handled by creating a trigger token which will allow you to create a new pipeline from an external source. All the steps are outlined [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/).

If you want to keep this implementation from GitLab side only, you can use the same strategy but trigger the pipeline from a CI/CD job. For example, by adding the trigger on your push to JFrog job as part of the `after_script` code. GitLab docs also cover how to [trigger a pipeline from a CI/CD job](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#use-a-cicd-job).

A simple example would be:

```
jfrog-push:
   image: your-image
   script:
      - authenticate to JFrog
      - push artifact to JFrog
   after_script:
      - 'curl --fail --request POST --form token=$MY_TRIGGER_TOKEN --form ref=main "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/123456/trigger/pipeline"'
```

That will create a new pipeline on the destination project. For this to work make sure to add the correct rules to allow the pipeline to be created:

- Use rules with the $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE predefined CI/CD variable, which will be `trigger`.
- Use only/except keywords, which is `triggers`.